# Array grouping valus with count

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with values

`Munnar, Cochin, Cochin, Cochin, Munnar, Cochin`

I need to group the values as

`Munnar(1), Cochin(3), Munnar(1), Cochin(1)`.

How can loop the array to get  the desired output.

Comment: You can use  array_count_values(). It will give you array

Comment: it will give answer like munnar(2), Cochin(4). I need the result exact as above

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
<?
$arrAux = array('Munnar', 'Cochin', 'Cochin', 'Cochin', 'Munnar', 'Cochin');

$count = 0;
$previous = $arrAux[0];
foreach ($arrAux as $name){
  if ($previous === $name)
     $count++;
  else{
     echo "{$previous}({$count})";
     $previous = $name;
     $count = 1;
  }
}
//Print last item
echo "{$previous}({$count})";
?>
```

This should do the work, i think that you don't want to use `array_count_values`. This function has been made in a minute so, perhaps it can be improved :)

Comment: He already have array :) no need to explode !!

Comment: Correct, i'll edit my answer, thanks

Comment: Working fine..Good! +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $arr = array('Munnar','Cochin','Cochin','Cochin','Munnar','Cochin');

$count = 0;
$previous=$arr[0]; 
$output = "";
 foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    if($arr[$key]==$previous){
      $count++;
    }
   else
   {
      $output .= $previous."(".$count.")";
     $count=1;
     $previous= $arr[$key];
   }
} 

if($previous==$arr[count($arr)-1])
    $output.=$previous."(".$count.")";


echo $output;
```

Comment: This function will count twice the first element and will not show the last element, this is why i print the last item when the `foreach` finish

Comment: this will print last item :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//print_r( array_count_values($yourarray));

$array=array_count_values($yourarray);
```

Now you can loop through the $array to get the desired result.

Comment: Not exactly what user asked for..

Comment: @Chandresh I guess he is asking for the array with count of the values.

Comment: No, he's asking for a count of consecutive values, so an array like this `(Munnar,Cochin,Munnar,Cochin,Munnar,Cochin)` will print `Munnar(1), Cochin(1), Munnar(1), Coching(1), Munnar(1), Cochin(1)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$array = array('Munnar','Cochin','Cochin','Cochin','Munnar','Cochin');
$vals = array_count_values($array);
echo 'No. of NON Duplicate Items: '.count($vals).'<br><br>';

  foreach($vals as $key=>$val){
echo $key."(".$val."),";
}
```

Output :

```
Munnar(2),Cochin(4)
```

Comment: I want array like [Munnar] => 1, [Cochin] => 3, [Munnar] => 1 , [cochin] => 1

Comment: OK please wait @Nisanth

Comment: @Nisanth You want Munnar(1), Cochin(3), Munnar(1), Cochin(1) this output or [Munnar] => 1, [Cochin] => 3, [Munnar] => 1 , [cochin] => 1 this output please explain

Answer (score 0):

I don't know perfectly PHP, but you can try:

```
$array = array('Munnar','Cochin','Cochin','Cochin','Munnar','Cochin');

$prev = "";
$count = 0;

foreach($array as $key)
{
   if(empty($prev))
   {
       $prev = $key;
       $count = 1;
       continue;
   }

   if($prev === $key)
   {
      $count++;
   } else {
      echo "($prev)($count)";
      $prev = $key;
      $count = 1;
   }
}

echo "($prev)($count)";
```

Comment: giving output `()(0)(Munnar)(1)(Cochin)(3)(Munnar)(1)(Cochin)(1)` which is not expected..

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
<?php
$key = '';
$_n = array();
$_a = array('Munnar', 'Cochin', 'Cochin', 'Cochin', 'Munnar', 'Cochin');
foreach ($_a as $_1) {
    if ($key != $_1) {
        $idx = count($_n[$_1]);
        if ( isset($_n[$_1][$idx]) ) $idx += 1;
        $_n[$_1][$idx] = 1;
        $key = $_1;
    }
    else {
        $idx = count($_n[$_1]) -1;
        $_n[$_1][$idx] += 1;
    }
}


foreach ($_n as $k1=>$v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $k2=>$v2) {
        echo 'Key: '.$k1.', Index:'.$k2.', Value:'.$_n[$k1][$k2].'<br/>';
    }
}
?>
```

The Result

```
Key: Munnar Index:0 Value:1
Key: Munnar Index:1 Value:1
Key: Cochin Index:0 Value:3
Key: Cochin Index:1 Value:1
```

If you need exact order as in your question

```
Munnar(1), Cochin(3), Munnar(1), Cochin(1)
```

You can use the above and assign at the innermost loop to a new array something like this:

```
$new_arr[] = array( $k1 => $_n[$k1][$k2] );
```

Caveat: Ensure that starting key will always be different in first comparison.